# How to list content of nested jars

Tags: binary-file

Suppose, I have a .jar file `a.jar`, which I can view via `vim a.jar`, giving a list of the content like:

```
a1.txt
a2.txt
b.jar
```

I can press enter and load the content of each file; however, for .jars inside this archive, I am more interested in the content listing than the binary content. In this case, I want enter to show me a similar view of `b.jar`, rather than it's binary content.

In other words, how can I show list of files of nested .jar files in vim?

Answer (score 1):

`.jar` files are essentially zip files (you'll probably have noticed the `" zip.vim version vxx` banner at the top of the buffer). There are a few plugins which aim to help open nested zips, so you could try one ([vim-rzip](https://github.com/lbrayner/vim-rzip), for example) as a possible fix.